# How to extract rspec tests into rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I'm extracting functionality into a rails app and I'm wondering what the best practice is for moving the specs over.

Should the specs be in a special namespaced directory?

`specs/my_engine`

The controllers and models exist within the correct namespace (i.e. engine's name), but I'm not sure what to do about the specs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to organize your specs in

```
specs/controllers/xxx_controller_spec.rb
specs/controllers/yyy_controller_spec.rb
specs/controllers/zzz_controller_spec.rb
```

then do the same for your models

```
specs/models/xxx_spec.rb
specs/models/yyy_spec.rb
specs/models/zzz_spec.rb
```

If you use factories, just another directory

```
specs/factories/xxx.rb
```

and so on.

If you have additional name spaces, copy the same structure in your rspec directories.

This keeps things well organized and structured, and you have a structure "mirroring" your implementation